# How to get the amount of virtual memory available in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, virtual-memory

I would like to map a file into memory using mmap function and would like to know if the amount of virtual memory on the current platform is sufficient to map a huge file. For a 32 system I cannot map file larger than 4 Gb.
Would `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()` give me the amount of addressable memory or is there any other type that I should test (off_t or something else)?

As Lie Ryan has pointed out in his comment the "virtual memory" here is misused. The question, however holds: there is a type associated with a pointer and it has the maximum value that defines the upper limit of what you can possibly adress on your system. What is this type? Is it size_t or perhaps ptrdiff_t?

Comment: "For a 32 system I cannot map file larger than 4 Gb." I think it's 2GB on Windows (or 3 if you throw an OS switch), because half (or a quarter, respectively) of your address space is reserved by the OS.

Comment: C++ does not require the existence of a virtual memory (heck, it doesn't even recognize the existence of a screen, or a RAM if that matters; the standard specifies behavior, not implementation, and virtual memory is implementation details); this will be highly platform specifics, so you'd need to specify your platforms you're developing for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_t` is only required to be big enough to store the biggest possible single contiguous object. That *may* not be the same as the size of the address space (on systems with a segmented memory model, for example)

However, on common platforms with a flat memory space, the two are equal, and so you can get away with using `size_t` in practice if you know the target CPU.

Anyway, this doesn't really tell you anything useful. Sure, a 32-bit CPU has a 4GB memory space, and so `size_t` is a 32-bit unsigned integer. But that says nothing about how much you can allocate. Some part of the memory space is used by the OS. And some parts are already used by your own application: for mapping the executable into memory (as well as any dynamic libraries it may use), for each thread's stack, allocated memory on the heap and so on.

So no, tricks such as taking the size of `size_t` tells you a little bit about the address space you're running in, but nothing very usable. You can ask the OS how much memory is in use by your process and other metrics, but again, that doesn't really help you much. It is possible for a process to use just a couple of megabytes, but have that spread out over so many small allocations that it's impossible to find a contiguous block of memory larger than 100MB, say. And so, on a 32-bit machine, with a process that uses nearly no memory, you'd be unlikely to make such an allocation. (And even if the OS had a magical `WhatIsTheLargestPossibleMemoryAllocationICanMake()` API, that *still* wouldn't help you. It would tell you what you needed *from a moment ago*. You have no guarantee that the answer would still be valid by the time you tried to map the file.

So really, the best you can do is *try* to map the file, and see if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use GlobalMemoryStatusEx and VirtualQueryEx if you coding in win32

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, the size of a pointer tells you nothing about how much of that "address space" is actually available to you, i.e. can be mapped as a single contiguous chunk.

It's limited by:

- the operating system. It may choose to only make a subset of the theoretically-possible address range available to you, because mappable memory is needed for OS-own purposes (like, say, making the graphics card framebuffer visible, and of course for use by the OS itself).
- configurable limits. On Linux / UNIX, the "ulimit" command resp. setrlimit() system call allows to restrict the maximum size of an application's address space in various ways, and Windows has similar options through registry parameters.
- the history of the application. If the application uses memory mapping extensively, the address space can fragment limiting the maximum size of "available" contiguous virtual addresses.
- the hardware platform. Some CPUs have address spaces with "holes"; an example of that is 64bit x86 where pointers are only valid if they're between 0x0..0x7fffffffffff or 0xffff000000000000 and 0xffffffffffffffff. I.e. you have 2x128TB instead of the full 16EB. Think of it as 48-bit "signed" pointers ...

Finally, don't confuse "available memory" and "available address space". There's a difference between doing a malloc(someBigSize) and a mmap(..., someBigSize, ...) because the former might require availability of physical memory to accommodate the request while the latter usually only requires availability of a large-enough free address range.

For UNIX platforms, part of the answer is to use getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS) as this gives the upper bound for the current invocation of your application - as said, the user and/or admin can configure this. You're guaranteed that any attempt to mmap areas larger than that will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Re your rephrased question "upper limit of what you can possibly adress on your system", is somewhat misleading; it's hardware architecture specific. There are 64bit architectures out there (x64, sparc) whose MMU happily allows (uintptr_t)(-1) as valid address, i.e. you can map something into the last page of a 64bit address space. Whether the operating system allows an application to do so or not is again an entirely different question ...

For user applications, the "high mark" isn't (always) fixed a-priori. It's tunable on e.g. Solaris or Linux. That's where getrlimit(RLIMIT_AS) comes in.

Note that again, by specification, there'd be nothing to prevent a (weird) operating system design to choose e.g. putting application stacks and heaps at "low" addresses while putting code at "high" addresses, on a platform with address space holes. You'd need full 64bit pointers there, can't make them any smaller, but there could be an arbitrary number of "inaccessible / invalid" ranges which never are made available to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sizeof(int*)`. This will give you the length (in bytes) of a pointer on the target platform. Thus, you can find out how big the addressable space is.

Comment: That's not valid : a lot of addresses are reserved by the system.

Comment: Also note that it is not guaranteed that any bit-pattern in a pointer is a valid address, so technically speaking 2 to the power of sizeof(int*) is not the available (or even potentially available) virtual memory

Comment: It does provide an upper bound, assuming a flat memory architecture. A *very* optimistic one, though, esp. on 64-bit systems.

Comment: +1 for the very optimistic one, I'm still waiting for a computer that will require the full 64 bits available to address its memory and I don't see it coming anytime soon.